# AngularJS select dropdown - Select default option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have AngluarJs dropdown, each option "onchange" will take navigate to another page. Here is the code:

```
   <select class="qtDropDown" 
           ng-model="Suggested" 
           ng-change="changeOption()" 
           ng-options="option.name for option in suggested">
```

Js.

```
     $scope.suggested = StrategyService.getPredefinedStrategies();
     $scope.Suggested = $scope.suggested[0];

     $scope.changeOption = function () {
        var selectedStrategy = $scope.Suggested;
        var queryString = selectedStrategy.name.split(' ').join(''); 
        window.location.href(baseUrl+queryString);
     };
```

The Problem here is When I click on the default selection which is  `$scope.suggested[0];` it is not navigating the user. Can anybody suggest where I am doing the mistake please ?

Comment: So you mean, change event doesn't fire unless you change actually options?

Comment: Not exactly, the change event is firing if you select any other option not default one which is  $scope.suggested[0].

Answer (score 2):

It's normal as when you select $scope.suggested[0] there is not change has it is your default.

One way to prevent it is by adding a blank option

```
<select class="qtDropDown" ng-model="Suggested" ng-change="changeOption()" 
ng-options="option.name for option in suggested">
    <option value=""> - Choose one of the following - </option>
</select>
```

That way, when you will select $scope.suggested[0], there will a change trigerred.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That's true but, I wanted to have a default option. That's the point. Any way, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

just trigger the changeOption function in your javascript :)

you are selecting the default option but you have the function that needs to be triggered when the value changes.. so just modify the code to :

```
     $scope.suggested = StrategyService.getPredefinedStrategies();

     $scope.changeOption = function () {
        var selectedStrategy = $scope.Suggested;
        var queryString = selectedStrategy.name.split(' ').join(''); 
        window.location.href(baseUrl+queryString);
     };     
     $scope.Suggested = $scope.suggested[0];
     $scope.changeOption(); // this will trigger the change of the default value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="qtDropDown" id="qtDropDown">
<option value="url">...</option>

var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'Select' );
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
window.open(  this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
};
```

with angular js, add ng-model in your div tag.